# How to separate links of images on the basis of content inside them in beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to BeautifulSoup4 and I am trying to fetch all image links from a site for eg.Unsplash but I only wan urls that contains word "photo" in there url eg.

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541892079-2475b9253785?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60

I don't want urls that contain word "profile" for eg.

https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1508728808608-d3781b017e73?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff

How can I do so I am using Pyhton 3.6 and urllib3 .

Comment: You could simply get them all then filter out the ones you don't want in your code.

Comment: Can you add a example with code ,as I am new to to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script as an example, how to filter the links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://unsplash.com'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    if 'photo' in img['src']:  # print only links with `photo` inside them
        print(img['src'])
```

Prints:

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597649260558-e2bd7d35f043?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1000&h=1000
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598929214025-d6bb6167d43b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599567513879-604247ea2bd3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599366611308-719895c34512?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598929214025-d6bb6167d43b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599366611308-719895c34512?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599567513879-604247ea2bd3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598929214025-d6bb6167d43b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599567513879-604247ea2bd3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599366611308-719895c34512?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80
```

---

With `urllib`:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://unsplash.com'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    if 'photo' in img['src']:
        print(img['src'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrej Kesely